# Lesser Limited Principle Of Omniscience

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, logic, constructive-mathematics

I have given the following Theorem:

Let $A = (a_1,\dots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that the rank of A is known and every $a_i$ is nonzero. Then the following holds
\begin{align*}
[\neg (\exists p \in P_n) ( Ap = 0) ] \Longrightarrow [(\exists \xi) ( \xi A > 0)],
\end{align*}
where $P_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that all entries in the vector are $> 0$ and sum up to $1$.

From this theorem I want to show LLPO: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n x \ge 0 \vee x \le 0$.

Please notice that the proof should be constructive, in particular the use of the law of excluded middle is prohibited.

The obvious idea is to define a suitable matrix A and verify LLPO. Therefore let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
I have tried multiple matrices such as

i) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & x \\
   x & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Problem: rank(A) is not known; the reason for this is that constructively $ \neg (x=0) \Rightarrow \vert x \vert > 0$ does NOT hold.

In the following matrices the assumptions of the theorem are always fulfilled, but I am never able to verify LLPO.

ii) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & x & 0 \\
   x & 0  & 1\\
   0 & 1 & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Problem: rank(A) is known, all columns are unequal 0 , Ap = 0 has no solution if I assume $\vert x \vert < \frac{1}{2}$ (which is allowed); then I have that $( \xi_1 + \xi_2 x  , \xi_1 x + \xi_3, \xi + \xi_3x ) > 0$. So there are three different cases: first entry is > 0 and the latter two are $\ge 0$; and the other two cases are given analogously. Now in the first case I have either $\xi_1 > 0 $ or $\xi_2 x > 0$. If the latter holds LLPO follows, but from the first I cannot show LLPO.

iii) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 1 \\
   1 & x \\
   x & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

iv) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & x & x\\
   x & x & 1 \\
   x & 1 & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

v) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   x & 1 \\
   1 & x \\
   x & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

vi) $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & x \\
   x & 1 \\
   0 & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

To be honest, I have run out of ideas of reasonable matrices; whence I would appreciate some new input resp. any idea in order to proof the LLPO from this theorem.

Edit: As Carl Mummert mentioned, the problem can be also viewed from a geometric standpoint. In this course, I want to state a "suitable" separating lemma.

Consider the following lemma:

Let $Y$ be a located, convex and inhabited set such that $ 0 \notin \mathring{Y}$ and $ \mathring{Y}$ is still located, convex and inhabited. Fix elements $y_1,\dots,y_l \in Y$ such that at all elements are non-zero. Then we have
        \begin{align*}
  \exists \xi \in Y : (\langle \xi, y_1\rangle,\dots,\langle \xi, y_l\rangle) > 0.
  \end{align*}

I already know that this lemma implies the theorem above. I also know that LLPO implies this lemma. Notice that I think it is possible to demand that all entries in the vector are $ > 0$ in both the theorem and the lemma. This might simplify the verification of the LLPO.

Edit 2: I don't think it is possible to show LLPO in this case. In my opinion suitable matrices are such that they have at least one column with only $x's$ and $0's$. But in this case it is not possible to know the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Is your formula $[\lnot (\exists p \in P_n) (A_p = 0)] \to [(\exists \xi) (\xi A > 0)]$?  I had trouble reading it originally.

Comment: @Carl: yes, I will fix it in the question.

Comment: It could have just been my eyes deceiving me in the morning. Thanks. I'm thinking about the problem, but I don't have a solution yet. I think you are right that, if there is an answer, it should come from a small matrix.

Comment: I am thinking about $
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -x \\
   x & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Comment: @Carl: Ok so I presume you assumed something like $\vert x\vert < 1$. So $rank(A)$ known, columns are not zero, $Ap= 0$ has no solution. Thus $(\xi_1 + \xi_2 x, - \xi_1 x + \xi_2 ) >0$. If the first entry is positive, either $\xi_1  > 0$ or $\xi_2 x> 0$. In the latter case LLPO holds, but in the first case I don't see how this verifies LLPO.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I want to try to think about the problem geometrically. We know the line where $\xi A = 0$ - are there regions where $\xi A> 0$ or $\xi A < 0$?  I don't have paper with me, and I'll need to mull it over.

Comment: @Carl: I think the idea of a geometric approach is very good. Earlier on I did show that some separating theorem implies the theorem from my question. I will put this Sep theorem in the original post.

Comment: @Carl: I am thinking that it is not possible to show. Even the MP property does not follow from this theorem, since , in order to know the rank of the matrix, I already need something like the MP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did think about this problem for quite some time now and I don't think its provable in this environment.

In order to know the rank of the matrix A, we need atleast one nonzero constant in every column. But if I have a nonzero constant in every column, I will come across a situation where I know that, f.e. $\xi_1 > 0$ and $\xi_1 x + \xi_2 \ge 0$. I this situation I cannot make any statements about the sign of x. Although this is only one example of a possible situation, it is rather obvious that any matrix A with known rank will lead to a problem like this. Hence I can't show LLPO.